# add javascript event to view

Tags: views, theming, javascript

I have no well enough experience in themeing with view, It is also the first project I used view. In this page, I would like to add javascript event to  qq under category_page.

When clicks qq I want to navigate to www.example.com/qq.  But I know I have to write javascript in its respective template file, my problem is which template file is suitable to write. I also upload screen shot, to clear my question.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: if you want to redirect you can also use views for that why you want to use js for that?

Comment: @harsh I agree. If category_page is the view that was created to output these links and all of these links have the same redirect pattern then just rewrite the links in views.